# NAS (enclosure or complete solution) recommendation for home/small office

Tags: data-storage, nas

I'm looking for recommendations on NAS for home / small office. Main purpose - storage of digital data (documents, photos, movies). Must to have RAID 1 capabilities. Can be enclosure only. Direct connection (access from a smartphone without connection via computer) will be a big plus. Min capacity 1TB (or diskless system) and 2 bays. Budget in a range between $150-$250

Comment: What is the minimum drive bays this NAS can contain?

Comment: @MikeJuneBugCaptain 2 bays for mirroring.

Comment: please make the title more descriptive, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title. IMHO you could mention that you're looking for a complete solution—as opposed to considering self-built setups as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you take a look at Synology.
I have a DS216+ and im very happy with it. Its a bit over your budget.

They also have a "j" version thats $160 here:
[https://www.amazon.com/Synology-DS216j-NAS-DiskStation/dp/B01BNPT1EG/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1469742885&sr=1-2&keywords=synology+ds216](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BNPT1EG)

and "se" thats even cheaper.

Should be able to do everything you need.
If you do install Plex on it, im not sure what performance you will get, because i have the "+" model its a bit more powerful. (you will be able to stream for sure, im not sure about transcoding)

more specs here:
https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS216j

https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS216se

Comment: DS216+ and DS216Play is it the same?

Comment: @JackTheKnife No if you look at the specs on both machines you will notice that the "play" has a 32bit ARM processor and it is more suited for multimedia applications (movies. music, etc). While the "+" is a 64bit x86 intel processor and is just generally "more" powerful/feature rich, can run more applications, hence more expensive. specs can be found here for bith boxes:  https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS216play#spec  https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS216+II#spec

Comment: @JackTheKnife I can probably recommend one of the 4 or so versions, if you can supply a typical use case in a day of the "life" of your NAS. How many people will use it concurrently? are you going to watch HD movies all the time, are you going to use the "dropbox like" capabilities. Examples like that will probably help you and me narrow down the choices so you can get the most "bang" for your money.

Comment: @JackTheKnife if all else fails i would go for the "play" its still in your budget and its got the most power. Not including the "+" (i'm not counting that cause its over budget). Read the review here: http://www.storagereview.com/synology_diskstation_ds216play_review the review says no Plex, but Plex officially supports it now

Comment: Is going to be 2+ people mostly (docs and photos = dropbox like) and maybe kids over the weekend for movies (plex)

Comment: Yeah i would say go with the "Play" version. Its on the high range of the budget but its worth it.  That should satisfy all your requirements. The cheaper versions will be a bit underpowered for Plex when you will want to play movies in HD.